# React 16 updates - changing the ref to a component

Tags: reactjs

I'm reading about the new [breaking changes](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#breaking-changes) of React 16 and I can't understand the following statement:

> Previously, changing the ref to a component would always detach the ref before that component’s render is called. Now, we change the ref later, when applying the changes to the DOM.

My questions are:

What does it mean by **changing the ref to a component**?

As I know you can only assign a ref to a component:

```
<input ref={ input => this.inputNode = input } />
```

Can someone give me a concrete examples of the two different behaviours described there?

Comment: this is not about the ref props i believe. this is about the reference of the react instance that is returned when you render.  https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render

Comment: hmm, interesting, I will take a look at this